# Incorrect results when using OpenMP

Tags: parallel-processing, fortran, openmp

I have written down a simple code using openmp in fixed form fortran.My code is running but the result produced by it is wrong.can anybody help me out?

```
    Implicit none   
    
    integer i,N,CHUNKSIZE
    parameter(N=100)
    parameter(CHUNKSIZE=7)
    double precision X(N), Y(N), XdotY
    integer :: threadNUM, OMP_GET_THREAD_NUM
    
    XdotY=0.0d0
!$OMP PARALLEL DO LASTPRIVATE(X,Y)
    do I=1,N
    X(I)=I
    Y(I)=I**2
    write(*,*) x(i),y(i)
    end do
!$OMP END PARALLEL DO
!$OMP PARALLEL DO 
C$OMP&REDUCTION(+:XdotY)
    do I=1,N
    XdotY = XdotY + X(I)*Y(I)
    end do
!$OMP END PARALLEL DO
    
    write(*,*)'X.Y=', XdotY
    write(*,*)'the exact answer is =', (N*(N+1)/2.0d0)**2
    
    end
```

Here the answer is not matching.
The following is the result -
X.Y=   17380000.000000000
the exact answer is =   25502500.000000000
And i am compiling it by the command - 'gfortran -fopenmp dotprod_OMP.f90 -o dotprod_OMP'.

also, i have done this in an f90 file.
the following is the code -
Implicit none

```
integer i
integer,parameter :: N=100
integer,parameter :: CHUNKSIZE=7
double precision  :: X(N), Y(N), XdotY
integer :: threadNUM, OMP_GET_THREAD_NUM

XdotY=0.0d0

!$OMP PARALLEL DO LASTPRIVATE(X,Y)
do I=1,N
X(I)=I
Y(I)=I**2
!write(*,*) x(i),y(i)
end do
!$OMP END PARALLEL DO

!$OMP PARALLEL DO 
!$OMP REDUCTION(+:XdotY)
do I=1,N
XdotY = XdotY + X(I)*Y(I)
end do
!$OMP END PARALLEL DO

write(*,*)'X.Y=', XdotY
write(*,*)'the exact answer is =', (N*(N+1)/2.0d0)**2

end
```

there is an error after compilation.
the error shows this -
25 |  !$OMP REDUCTION(+:XdotY)
|       1
Error: Unclassifiable OpenMP directive at (1)

I think the reduction clause is not working. how can i solve this?

Comment: Note this code is at least Fortran90 - I have reflected this in my edits.

Comment: You haven't initialized X or Y. This code can give any answer it wants. And quite possibly a different answer every time it is run.  What happens if you do initialize  X and Y?

Comment: yes i have initialized like this -

Comment: !$OMP PARALLEL DO LASTPRIVATE(X,Y)
 do I=1,N
 X(I)=I
 Y(I)=I**2
 write(*,*) x(i),y(i)
 end do
!$OMP END PARALLEL DO

Comment: Please edit the question to show the *exact* code you are using - please don't put code in comments, it is close to unreadable.

Comment: sorry for that,i have already edited the question by rewriting the code.

Comment: by the answer is not matching i mean the value of 'X.Y' is not matching with 'the exact answer'.

Comment: X.Y is a real number. Is the difference of the order 1e-15? Or much bigger? If it is the former they probably are the same. If it is much bigger there is a problem. Please shows us our output in the question. How you are compiling it would be useful as well, along with the compiler version

Comment: I've also just cut and paste the above into a file and it won't compile - the formatting is wrong for fixed formatting as the number of spaces at the start of the line is incorrect. Could you please fix this, or better move to free-format which should have been the default for well over 3 decades now.

Comment: i have written and compile it in a f90 file too.let me add this into my question.

Comment: 1) I also guess that `lastprivate` is the culprit here; 2) in the f90 code, juste put `reduction` on the same line than `parallel`: `!$OMP PARALLEL DO REDUCTION(+:XdotY)`

Comment: @PierU I'm trying to imagine, and failing, what that `lastprivate` clause would mean and why it would make a difference. The compiler figures that only the last iteration is meaningful and throws away the rest?

Comment: @VictorEijkhout as I understand it, the X and Y arrays are private to each thread, and the version that is kept at the end of the parallel region is the one from the thread that executed the last sequential iteration (`i`=`n here)`. Anyway, whichever the version that is retained at the end, it is incomplete.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark yes you were right.i have deleted last private part now it is running accurately.

Answer (score 0):

From the Microsoft Learn documentation of OpenMP which states that the `lastprivate` clause:

> Specifies that the enclosing context's version of the variable is set
> equal to the private version of whichever thread executes the final
> iteration (for-loop construct) or last section.

(I also checked the OpenMP specification (v5.2) which states the same, but at much more length and with many more ifs and buts, none of which are applicable here.  And I'm fairly sure that the fundamental behaviour of `lastprivate` hasn't changed since either OpenMP 1.0 or since when MS wrote their documentation.)

In this case `lastprivate` means that only the updates made to `X` and `Y` by one thread 'escape' to the rest of the program.  The fact that OP writes (and my own tests confirm) that removing the clause fixes the program makes me believe that the wrong use of the clause was the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think that a continuation should be placed on the following lines (although this may have changed with later versions of OpenMP?)
!$OMP PARALLEL DO &
!$OMP REDUCTION(+:XdotY)

The following modified code appears to produce the correct result.

```
implicit none
integer i
integer,parameter :: N=100
integer,parameter :: CHUNKSIZE=7
double precision  :: X(N), Y(N), XdotY
integer :: threadNUM, OMP_GET_THREAD_NUM

XdotY=0.0d0

!$OMP PARALLEL DO default(none) shared(x,y)
do I=1,N
   X(I)=I
   Y(I)=I**2
!write(*,*) x(i),y(i)
end do
!$OMP END PARALLEL DO

!$OMP PARALLEL DO default(none) shared(x,y) &
!$OMP REDUCTION(+:XdotY)
do I=1,N
   XdotY = XdotY + X(I)*Y(I)
end do
!$OMP END PARALLEL DO

write(*,*)'X.Y=', XdotY
write(*,*)'the exact answer is =', (N*(N+1)/2.0d0)**2

end
```

I have :-
included implicit none and default(none) as these provide better diagnostics,
Treated X and Y as shared,
Provided a continuation in !$omp syntax.

I am not sure why you did no get an error without the continuation, but this may relate to the OpenMP version you have available. I am using Gfortran Ver 11.1 on Win 10. This does not support OpenMP Ver 5.

For clarification, you could report the thread number uses for each "i" in either loop.